# javascript file storing

Tags: php, javascript

I have stored javascript files in the header.php of my project page. And overtime this has grown to lot of files. Need a help from senior member who can guide me how to store these? I looked all over net could not find anything on this. So this is my last stop.
Should these be stored in header.php(so what i am doing is correct?). Should these be stored individually on the .php pages that are using them? Or is there another better and more efficient way to do this?
(i do have some prototype and scriptaculous files also)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/prototype.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/scriptaculous.js"></script>

<script src="javascript/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery.noConflict();          
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/friends.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/site.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/search.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/settings.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/inbox.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/profile.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/color_picker.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/load_more.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='javascript/jquery.bgiframe.min.js'></script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='javascript/jquery.Queue.js'></script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='javascript/jquery.autocomplete.js'></script>
```

Comment: how much of that do you need inline? If you're waiting for `document.ready` for all of your calls, place all your scripts right before `</body>` so that you're not slowing down the load time with loading and execution of scripts.

Comment: @zzzzBov by inline you mean within header? Also you are saying place these in </body> element of what? Header.php file?

Comment: I had assumed you meant placing the scripts in the `head` element of the page. You made no mention of `php` as a language. By `inline` i meant any scripts that would be executed immediately after the content that they affect. By `</body>` i meant immediately before the `body` element's closing tag.

Comment: Sorry i did not mean to cause confusion. I updated it. But i have a header.php which is being included in all files. So all these .js files are being loaded on each page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loading 15 scripts here, including 3 libraries! That is complete overkill and will slow down your pages. You should never have more than a couple of Javascript files: every extra file makes an extra HTTP request which is the #1 cause of slow pages.

At an absolute minimum you should combine all the files into one. You can use [Google's Closure Compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com) to do this which will also minimize the code.

However, your much larger problem is that you are using 3 different libraries simultaneously. I'm guessing you found some nice scripts on the internet like lightboxes, but each script uses a different library. You could certainly split your code into 3 files with each library and their plugins (i.e. all the jQuery stuff in one file, Scriptaculous in another) and just call one of them per page.

However, I would suggest starting from scratch and **choosing one library**, then find plugins just for that library. jQuery is the most popular and you are likely to find equivalent plugins for it. Combine all that into one Javascript fileand include it on every page. This way, users have only one file to download that will be cached for later requests.

Comment: Mainly good advice, but not necessarily true; if your .js is served properly with a long cache time and told not to revalidate, no HTTP requests will sent for them, so having many script tags is not really a problem.  However, I doubt very much that the OP is doing the right cache control here, so it probably is a problem in their case.

Comment: @El Yobo: But you still have the 15 requests on initial page load, which is a heck of a lot! More than likely each of those plugins is no more than a few kB so the HTTP request is a larger portion of the overall download time.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript modularization really is a PITA.

I personaly use the module handling features from Dojo toolkit, but there are standalone module systems like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) that also do this. (I don't know what is the "traditional" solution for this in JQuery-land though)

If you don't want or can't use one of these module-handling libraries, you will need to structure everything by hand, so for every feature you will need to include its script tag on every single page that needs to use it (and in the correct order, if there are dependencies).

---

If it is taking too long to load all your scripts, there are some performance related things you can consider doing:

1. Merge some groups of related scripts into single, large, files. This will reduce the number of requests made to the server. (And reduce the number of script taggs in your HTML, as a bonus)
2. Put your script tags at the end of the `<body>` instead of at the `<head>`. This way the browser at least gets to render the rest of the page first before stoping to load scripts.

Comment: i would also look at compressing and g-ziping your scripts if performance is an issue.

Answer (score 0):

First off all on a given page load only those js files which are required.

Secondly its best to us [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) if you have too many js files.